# Mysql table relation for a user with multiple business

Tags: mysql, database

How to properly implement mysql table relation such that a user can create multiple business and each of those business can have multiple users. thanks

Comment: Off topic for this forum please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Basically going to be two (possibly 3 tables):

Business Table:
business_id int (this will be the primary key)
business_name
whatever extra fields that relate to the business

User Table:
user_id whatever type (this will be the primary key)
user_name
whatever extra fields that relate to the business

The relational part you can implement in one of two ways:

1. add the business id to the user table.  So user table will have an additional field business_id and will relate back to one of the rows in the business table.  This implies a user can only relate to 1 business.
2. If you want a user to be able to relate to one or more businesses then you need a separate table:
   Business_User Table:
   business_id int
   user_id (whatever type you picked)

Comment: What about adding users to the business created by  the user example adding employee to the business created by a user